# Geoserver: WFS/WMS query by month on Date datatype

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, filter, ogc

I have a GeoServer running, using a Postgis database as storage for a workspace with a few different layers. These layers are accessible through WMS or WFS. One of the variables in this database is stored as a Date.

How should I create a ogc:filter that would allow me to select all variables for a specific month (An example could be: "select all data from June-August in 1990-1995"). I'd like this to work on both the WMS and the WFS services, but in general I think most solutions would?

I tried to use the PropertyIsLike-operator as if date was a string, but that did not work. Here is a case where I try to get all data from the month of May:

```
http://localhost:8090/geoserver/testWorkspace/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&OUTPUTFORMAT=json&TYPENAME=elTestLayero&PROPERTYNAME=date&FILTER=
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <PropertyIsLike wildCard='*' singleChar='.' escapeChar='!'>
        <PropertyName>date</PropertyName>
        <Literal>....-05-..</Literal>
    </PropertyIsLike>
</ogc:Filter>
```

That would return this exception:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOException null ERROR: operator does not exist: 
        date ~~ unknown Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
        You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 83
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
```

It suggests that I add explicit type cast. How can I do that?

Other possible solutions I thought of:

- Make a String variable which is just the same as the date variable (or I could simply add the month as a variable) in the database, and use this the way I tried to use date. This would however make the layer(s)/database slightly bigger, could it decrease the performance?
- Write an more advanced sql-view for the layer with a where clause where the month(s) come from SQL view parameters. I wouldn't prefer this solution because it would require that the layer was set up in a certain way, and I'd like my software to handle different layers in a quite dynamic way.

Answer (score 3):

If you know it'll always be by month, then I think your second suggested solution is the nicest, with the view column using *EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP myTimestamp) AS month_of_the_year* allowing you to use use a GreaterThan/LessThan ogc filter on the month number (see below).  Although the string match solution probably should work, it's not going to be as efficient as between filter.

```
<ogc:And>
 <!-- Between 1990 and 1996 -->
 <ogc:And>
  <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>datetime</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>1990-01-01 00:00:00</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
   <ogc:PropertyName>datetime</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>1996-01-01 00:00:00</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
 </ogc:And>
 <!-- Between June and August -->
 <ogc:And>
  <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyName>month_of_the_year</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
 <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyName>month_of_the_year</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
</ogc:And>
```

Alternatively, you could just loop through each year with the full start and end dates with:

```
<ogc:Or>
 <ogc:And>
  <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>datetime</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>*start_date_first_year*</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>datetime</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>*end_date_first_year*</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
 </ogc:And>
 ...
  repeat for each year
 ...
</ogc:Or>
```